# LDAPException: Invalid Credentials (49) Invalid Credentials with grails

Tags: java, grails, ldap, bind, openldap

These are the imports that I am using:

```
import com.novell.ldap.*;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
```

and I am trying to do a very simple password validation that I found at:

http://developer.novell.com/documentation/samplecode/jldap_sample/index.htm

and I can't seem to get the bind to work. Does anyone have a better way of doing this with grails or java. I am finding myself really lost and any examples or guidance would help.

Thanks.

Comment: Those aren't plugins, they're imports. Are you using a plugin?

Comment: your right, my bad. I was using the gldapo plugin and then I switched to these imports. Sorry for the mix up

Answer (score 1):

This Java example uses the [UnboundID LDAP SDK](http://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/) to connect and bind to a directory server. Run it like:

```
$ java -cp YOUR_CLASSPATH BindExample hostname port bindDn password
```

BindExample.java:

```
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.BindRequest;
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.BindResult;
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.Control;
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPConnection;
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPException;
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.ResultCode;
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.SimpleBindRequest;

public final class BindExample {

    public static void main(String... args) {
    if(args.length == 4) {
        final String hostname = args[0];
        final String dn = args[2];
        final String password = args[3];
        int port;
        LDAPConnection ldapConnection;
        try {
            port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        } catch(NumberFormatException nfx) {
            System.err.println(args[1] + " is not an integer, using 389");
            port = 389;
        }
        try {
            ldapConnection =
                new LDAPConnection(hostname,port);
        } catch(final LDAPException lex) {
            System.err.println("failed to connect to "
                   + hostname + " " +
                   lex.getMessage());
            return;
        }
        try {
            final BindRequest bindRequest =
                new SimpleBindRequest(dn,password);
            BindResult bindResult = 
                ldapConnection.bind(bindRequest);
            if(bindResult.getResultCode() == ResultCode.SUCCESS) {
                System.out.println("authentication successful");
            }
            if(bindResult.hasResponseControl()) {
                Control[] controls = 
                    bindResult.getResponseControls();
                // handle response controls ...
            }
            ldapConnection.close();
        } catch(final LDAPException lex ) {
            System.err.println("bind failed");
            ldapConnection.close();
            return;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your post. I solved my problem this morning with a co-worker. When putting in the host file, I was putting in the whole ldap url, where I should have just put the url